# Bitwise operation and Extension method with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, extension-methods, queryover

I want to query a table with numeric columns that contains flags.

I've built a mapping with NHibernate XML against a SQL Server 2008 database (I show you only interesting part):

This is my enum:

```
[Flags]
    public enum DocsFlag
    {
        FLAG_TOREAD = 0,
        FLAG_READ = 2,
        FLAG_MANAGED = 4,
        FLAG_INUSE = 8,
        FLAG_FORWARDED = 16,
        FLAG_RESUBMITTED = 32,
        FLAG_PRINTED = 64,
    }
```

this is my class:

```
public class MyObject
    {
      ...
      public virtual DocsFlag Flags { get; set; }
    }
```

Here my class db mapping:

```
<class name="MyObject">
    ...
    <property name="Flags" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

I want to query with strongly typed `QUERYOVER` :

```
_session.QueryOver<MyObject>()
        .Where(x => x.Error != null & (x.Flags && (DocsFlag.FLAG_READ | DocsFlag.FLAG_MANAGED | DocsFlags.FLAG_PRINTED)> 0))
        .Left.JoinQueryOver<DestinationObj>(m => m.Destination)
        .Left.JoinQueryOver<UsersObj>(x => x.LinkedUser).ToList();
```

Or simply:

```
.Where (x=> x.Flags && (DocsFlag.FLAG_READ | DocsFlag.FLAG_MANAGED | DocsFlags.FLAG_PRINTED)> 0)
```

But it doesn't work....

**What is the best way to query bit flags with nhibernate `QueryOver`?**

I tried these solutions:

1. I think to query directly with `createSqlQuery` but my query are very complex and I want to take advantage of `QueryOver` API.
2. I have begin my project with Linq to Nhibernate, but I've found a lot of bugs and I have noticed that there are not full support for query...
3. Write my own `QueryOver` extension methods to query flags columns but it's too early for me because I didn't understand how to `QueryOver` API transform code lambda functions in SQL query (and apply appropriate dialect).

Help me to find the best way...

Comment: Not related to what you ask, but did you intend to write `FLAG_TOREAD = 1,`?

Comment: Try by replacing `&&` with `&`(Bitwise AND). You can also use `x.Flags.HasFlag(...)`

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Flags & (DocsFlag.FLAG_TOHANDLE | DocsFlag.FLAG_DESTROYED )>0)` compiler tell me: Delegate 'System.Func<bool>' does not take 1 argumentsSystem.Enum:Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Flags.HasFlag(DocsFlag.FLAG_TOHANDLE | DocsFlag.FLAG_DESTROYED ))` runtime exception: Unrecognised method call: System.Enum:Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)

Comment: @davymartu use  more  parentheses . HasFlag maybe only in .Net 4.5, I haven't checked.

Comment: @I4V copy and paste error... i found on nhibernate api for 'HasFlags': Checked only for EntityFramework. It doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

the I also ran into this problem but apparently this doesn't work in QueryOver (yet).
Issue NH-2709 logged in jira describes this bug. See: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2709

According to a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nhusers/-mQd7_uiaO0/LLTLTKtAQzgJ) in the google group "nhusers" you could try HQL syntax or 
try the LINQ provider (.Query<>) to accomplish this.

However, there is also the following "monstrous" work-around in QueryOver that does the trick. Is uses `Projections` to create a fragment of SQL code that makes it work.

Replace your

```
.Where (x=> x.Flags && (DocsFlag.FLAG_READ | DocsFlag.FLAG_MANAGED) > 0)
```

with

```
.Where(
    Restrictions.Gt(
        Projections.SqlProjection(String.Format("({{alias}}.Flags & {0}) as DocFlagsSet",
                                                (int)(DocsFlag.FLAG_READ | DocsFlag.FLAG_MANAGED)),
                                  null, null)
    , 0)
```

It creates the following SQL statement:

```
WHERE (this_.Flags & 6) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but there is some way with linq

```
.Where(x => (x.Enum & Permission.Read) == Permission.Read)
```

Comment: QueryOver is not part of Linq, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @ToddHale Yes, and I informed about it in answer. But replacing QueryOver with Query is not difficult in most cases, so for some (like me) it will be easier than writing sql projection